# Are there any words in English that have a plural with a separate derivation?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, irregular, suppletion

There are some irregular plurals in English (child/children, goose/geese), but all of the ones I know of share the same root word.

In some languages, there are some irregular pairs where the singular form does not have the same root as the plural form, such as in Russian (год/лет, человек/люди).

Are there any such irregular plurals in English?

Comment: In what sense would any such singular/plural pair be *the same word* if they didn't have the same derivation? Why can't I point to *"God"* and *deities* as a pair of **different** words that from my point of view are singular/plural designations of the same referent(s)?

Comment: The technical term for this is [*suppletion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion). Linked from that Wikipedia article you will find the corresponding [Wiktionary category](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Suppletion), one of whose subcategories is [English nouns with suppletive plurals](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_nouns_with_suppletive_plurals).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Because the plural of *god* is *gods*. If one is counting gods, he is unlikely to say *one god, two deities*, whereas if he were counting people, there would be no such weirdness in saying *one person, two people*.

Comment: @RegDwight ΒВB♦: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that in English at least, *suppletion* (not a word recognised by my spell-checker) simply applies to things like *be, am, is, are, were*. I personally don't think these are different forms of "a word".

Comment: @Peter Olson: My point is that there's "a word" *person*, which has a regular plural. There's **another word** *people*, which can substitute for *persons* (but of course it also has a valid plural *peoples*). I simply don't see what OP is getting at when he asks for "a word" where the singular and plural have no shared etymology. There are a few English contexts (mainly in respect of very common verbs like "to be") where the same meaning is conveyed by words with different roots, but for me, that means they are not *the same word*.

Comment: ...in short, this is not a constructive question. It simply asks for a list of word-pairs where one is more common for singular, and the other for plural. There are lots of those.

Comment: @FumbleFinger I'm not sure this is a list question because OP is only asking if there are these special word, not what they are. I vote up.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "In linguistics and etymology, *suppletion* is traditionally understood as **the use of one word as the inflected form of another word when the two words are not cognate**." I can't vouch for the truth of this; it's the lead-in of the Wikipedia article.

Comment: In some circles the plural of anecdote is data.

Comment: @Carlo_R: Your use of the term "special word" again imputes some meaning to the word **word** which I simply don't accept as constructive. What's the plural of "toast", for example? Or the singular of "furniture"? As I said, there are some vestigial cases where *different **words** with different etymologies* have the same *meaning* but are used in different contexts (forms of what we call the "verb" *to be*, for example). But fairly obviously to me at least, these are not in fact aspects of the same "word" in any meaningful sense.

Comment: @MetaEd: I don't argue with that definition. English has a word **good**, but it doesn't have the "words" **gooder** or **goodest**, for example. In practice, in English, suppletion only seems to apply to a handful of ultra-common verbs and adjectives. So far as I'm concerned, the situation in respect of **nouns** is summed up by [this wiktionary page](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_nouns_with_suppletive_plurals) - and I don't accept their only example (person/people) as two aspects of the same "word" in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I disagree. The OP is clearly asking about suppletion, though he doesn't know what to call it, and as such the question is interesting an answerable.

Comment: @JSBձոգչ: I think *suppletion* is a word which arises "after the fact", where a single area of semantic space is "colonised" by **different words** from different "languages" (dialects, whatever) being assimilated into standard English. Rarely, it happens that a word with one origin gains ascendancy in one context (past plural verb form **were**, for example), where another (present singular **am**) survives in another context. Language tends towards regular inflexions, and only really common words (a few verbs, and even fewer adjectives) can resist that tendency. All you can do is list them.

Comment: Great question...I don't know what @FumbleFingers problem is.

Comment: @Mitch: In truth, I think my problem is simply the implication that *go/went, is/were*, and *person/people* (the only plausible noun put forward thus far) are different forms of *the same word*. They aren't - they're *different* words (with different etymologies) that happen to cluster around a single semantic space that in other circumstances might be covered by *a single word* with different inflections. In short, my problem is with OP's implicit definition of "word".

Comment: ...given OP has put forward an example in Russian, perhaps he would consider *finger/thumb* to be two different forms of what [to a Russian are arguably the same word](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70397/). I think in practice with nouns either the meanings of two closely-related words will diverge, or one will fall into disuse. The chances that one will only survive in the singular, and the other only in the plural, are negligible - but I'm sure all nouns that can meaningfully have singular/plural forms do in fact have them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think that is cavilling about what 'word' means. you have an X, what do you call it? You have more than one X, what do you call that. If X is 'person', more than one is (most naturally) called 'people'. By that informal but useful measure, 'cow'/'cattle' might work (but 'cows' is more likely).

Comment: @Mitch: So your definition of "a word" is "what you call something", and you think it's still "a word" regardless of whether you're talking about one or several of it? I think we must agree to differ, since my definition is more like "a symbol commonly understood by speakers of a language". By my definition, *person/people* are two different words, whereas *person/persons* and *people/peoples* are each two different forms of the same word. Which are in any case at best only close synonyms in certain contexts.

Comment: @Fum: I understand your point, but what you are basically saying is that you think suppletion is a misguided concept, because "go" and "went" just aren't the same "word" to you. Whether not they are one "word" or not is open to (a not very interesting terminology) debate. In suppletion, what is meant is that you would use the pair "go"-"went" just the same way as "move"-"moved", i.e. the relation between each pair is very similar. The question is, does English have such noun pairs (or trios etc.)? The answer is: perhaps "person"-"people", but otherwise none that we can think of. Seems valid.

Comment: @Cerberus: I do accept the concept of suppletion. I'm just saying it's a way of describing what happens when **two words** occupy the same (or at least, overlapping) semantic space. Normally what happens then unless one falls into disuse is that the actual meanings diverge. In a few cases, the split cuts across grammatical rather than semantic boundaries - practically all either verb tenses, or adjectival superlatives. The real question is why doesn't it happen with nouns in English? With *person/people* the standard plurals are valid, so I find it marginal compared to *good, gooder, goodest*.

Comment: ...anyway, I've done with my rant about "word". Apart from that I do think it's interesting that the phenomenon is so rare/doesn't exist in respect of noun plurality. Though presumably at some point in the past it **did** exist for *pig/pork, cow/beef, sheep/mutton* before English settled on those second forms to mean the butchered/cooked versions. So there's enough in it for me to vote for re-opening.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I can understand that you should find person/people marginal. At first you seemed to be averse to any noun suppletion (perhaps I misunderstood your point), but I think we are now agreed.

Answer (score 14):

Notwithstanding that I voted to close, I'm going to stick my neck out and say there are **no** ["English nouns with suppletive plurals"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aEnglish_nouns_with_suppletive_plurals). With the possible exception of *person/people* per Wiktionary link.

But I would point out that both those are singular words in their own right, with regular plurals *(persons/peoples)*. It just so happens that *people* is often used as a plural anyway (similar to *one fish, two fish*).

It's also worth noting that *person* can be used in contexts where *people* can't - for example, *"He carries a pistol on his person"*, but not **"They carry pistols on their people"*. Correspondingly, *"The good people of London welcome all to the Olympics"*, but not **"The good persons of London..."*

Valid examples of [suppletion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion) in English consist of a few common verbs *(to be - am, is, were, are)* and adjectives *(good - better, best)*. The phenomenon can only occur with common words, because with uncommon words the natural tendency of speakers to "regularise" inflections will triumph.

Comment: The other common verb that is formed from two distinct older ones is *to go*, which once upon a time stole its past form, *went*, from *to wend*. Interestingly, the two most common verbs in other western languages than English that show this are again *to be* and *to go*. They also have irregular degrees of adjectives in the same places, going from *bad* to *worse*, so to speak.

Comment: @Daniel: I'm in two minds now as to whether I still endorse my original closevote. I personally don't consider *am, is, were, are* or *go, went* to be variants of "a word", so I guess I'm just stamping my foot a bit over the "wording" of the question. Disregarding *person/people*, I think with nouns the closest we have is things like *cow/beef, pig/pork, sheep/mutton*. The English peasants had their own "animal" words, but they ended up using the French equivalents solely for the cooked meat their Norman overlords demanded be served at table.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, I'm sure you're right that other languages have this same phenomenon - and that the two ultra-common verbs *to be* and *to go* are always going to be likely candidates. Such irregularities can only survive when they're so common everyone knows the "correct" form. And if some peasant says *"I be a peasant"* - well, we know he's a peasant before he even gets the last word out, don't we!

Comment: Big +1 for going on the "Evidence of absence" argument. I believe you are correct, mainly in part because English nouns are particularly mutable, i.e., nouns that should have been or were traditionally irregular tend to morph into regular forms.

Comment: @nicholas: "mutable" looks like a good word in this context. It's my opinion that English (and probably all languages) tends to move towards regular inflections. Which may be part of why many people leap at the chance to speak of computer *mouses*, and most of us call our male siblings *brothers* rather than *brethren*.

Answer (score 11):

The following pairs have plurals with stems different from those of the singular forms:

**Personal pronouns**

*I* and *we*

*he/she/it* and *they*

**Possessive pronouns**

*mine* and *ours*

*his/hers* and *theirs*

**Possessive determiners**

*my* and *our*

*his/her/its* and *their*.

Answer (score 7):

[I think person/people is as close (or far) as it gets.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural)

Comment: What was the link going to be? :)

Comment: As @Malvolio points out that person-people is often quoted as a suppletive noun, it is not strictly so. Both are distinct nouns with distinct plurals - people just happens to be a collective or group noun. This is analogous to pig / swine and cow / cattle.

Comment: @nicholas: It isn't analogous because `swine` is not the standard plural for `pig` and `cattle` is not the standard plural for `cow`. But `people` is the standard plural for `person`. If you said "one car, two cars; one pig, two ..." most English speakers would say *pigs*, not swine. If you said "one person, two ..." most English speakers would say *people*, not persons.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I suppose you are right. Although person / people is historically analogous to pig / swine (cow / cattle is a different matter altogether), in modern usage it's meaning has changed. For consistent connotation, we have to say "3 people, 2 people, 1 person," because "1 people" means something different. The word "person" does not have this form of semantic switching - "3 persons, 2 persons, 1 person" is perfectly valid - but by convention, modern English speakers do not use it.

Answer (score 5):

Person/people.

Both words have additional plurals as well.

Comment: Surely the *actual* plural of "person" is "persons". As in the legal standard *"by persons unknown"*.

Comment: As well, the plural of "people" is "peoples," as in "the people of Spain" vs. "the peoples of Europe."

Comment: I don't agree with the distinction you make about the "actual" plural. There are different plurals used in different situations. In legal contexts one can find all sorts of uncommon constructions. And "people" has additional meanings. But if you ask a native speaker in normal circumstances, they will call one individual 'one person' and a pair of them 'two people'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Try it. Say to someone, "One car, two cars. One person, two ..." I'm pretty sure you'll hear "people" a lot more than "persons". Though "persons" is not incorrect, it has been almost completely supplanted by "people" as the plural for "person".

Answer (score 4):

Cow has three plurals: *cows* (which comes from "cow"), *cattle* (from from Anglo-Norman *catel*, meaning "chattel"), and *kine* (which comes from *ku*, also the ancient root of "cow", so might not count).

Comment: Cattle is not the plural of cow. Or at least, cow is not the singular of cattle. A cow is a calving female. There is no good English singular for cattle.

Comment: @Mark How about *beeve*?

Comment: @MarkBeadles -- mmm, I see your point, but if you showed a native English speaker 100 cows and asked him what they are, he'd answer "cattle".  I suppose "domestic bovine animal" is the most common thing that has no name in English.

Comment: [One cow, two kine. One sow, two swine.](http://a-t-rain.livejournal.com/41164.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's not used very often nowadays, but there's *cow* and *[kine](http://www.wordnik.com/words/kine)*.

Comment: Those appear to have the same derivation.

Comment: Still the same root, though, like _sow_ and _swine_. The plural is the same as in _oxen_ and _children_, and the vowel change is ordinary umlaut, like _mouse - mice_.

Comment: @WAF & John L.: Perhaps so; it was the closest second example I could offer, and seemed worthy of a mention at least.

Comment: Wow, missed it by *that much* : "cattle"

Comment: Erm... [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=kine) says *genitive plural of M.E. kye "cows," from O.E. cy (gen. cyna), plural of cu "cow."* To me, that means they have "the same derivation".

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe "*cow* and *kine*" is the answer to a quirky trivia question: What is the only singular/plural word pair that share no common letters?  (I realize this doesn't refute the fact that they share the same root, but thought it was interesting to note).

Comment: They do have the same derivation. In any case, 'kine' doesn't exist to fill any gap created by the absence of any other plural for 'cow'. It's just an old form.

Answer (score -2):

Cow

Kine - archaic, but still occasionally used plural. If you are connected to agriculture, you might hear it more than once a year.

Comment: Several other answers have mentioned this already.