# English nouns whose plural form differs from singular

Tags: nouns, irregular-plurals

The singular of *people* is *person*. For example, if there are three people in a room, you would refer to one of them as a person. There other English nouns of this type, e.g. cattle vs cow/bull. Is there a name for this class of nouns in which the singular and plural forms are not related?

Comment: The singular of *cattle* is either *cow* or *bull*, depending on the gender. And if you object on the basis that the plural of *cow* is *cows*, remember that the plural of *person* is *persons*.

Comment: The plural of "person" is "persons"; " people" as noun is used both as plural as well as singular (in which case its plural is peoples).

Comment: [Irregular plural nouns](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/irregular-plural-nouns/) also [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/irregular-plural-nouns-in-english-1692634).

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul I was a litte nervous when "octopi" showed up in the "irregular plural nouns" link but the article regained some points when it defended "octopuses" and mentioned "octopodes"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the correct plural of person?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62084/whats-the-correct-plural-of-person)

Comment: 'The plural of _person_ is _people_' / 'the singular of _people_ is _person_' invokes a technicality (fudge) known as 'suppletion'. Strictly, as the two are different lexemes, one cannot 'be the plural of' the other.

Comment: 'The singular and plural forms of a noun' cannot be different lexemes. 'Cow' or 'head' or 'neat', and 'cattle', are _different nouns_. 'Cow' and 'neat' are single-form and take singular agreement and refer to a single referent; 'cattle' takes plural agreement and refers to multiple referents (I'm not sure about whether it's singular in form); 'head' is singular in form, takes plural agreement (never '1 head of cattle') and correspondingly refers to multiple referents. // You're looking for a subset of lexical gaps / lacunas.

Comment: 'Suppletive plurals' is a string given at [Are there any words in English that have a plural with a separate derivation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74227/are-there-any-words-in-english-that-have-a-plural-with-a-separate-derivation). FumbleFingers argues that the class 'suppletive plurals' is non-existent A strong argument that 'people' should not be seen as the plural form of 'person' is that 'he had it on his person' cannot be pluralised to 'they had it on their people'.

Comment: @PeterShor "cow" and "bull" refer to different sexes of cattle, not gender.

Comment: It's more complicated than that! See [Cattle - Farm Stay Skagit at Hoehn Bend Farm](https://farmstayskagit.com/cattle-the-cows/#:~:text=A%20cow%20is%20a%20female,that%20is%20able%20to%20breed.) and [How to determine if cattle are bulls, steers, cows or heifers](https://www.farmanddairy.com/top-stories/how-to-determine-if-cattle-are-bulls-steers-cows-or-heifers/274534.html#:~:text=Quickest%20way%20to%20determine%20gender).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article on [suppletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion#Irregularity_and_suppletion):

> In linguistics and etymology, **suppletion** is traditionally understood as the use of one word as the inflected form of another word when the two words are not cognate. For those learning a language, suppletive forms will be seen as "irregular" or even "highly irregular".

It gives both cow/cattle and person/people as examples, though person/people is “incomplete suppletion”. Suppletion covers more than just nouns though, including verbs like be/am/is/was/were, so the term you are specifically looking for is **suppletive plurals** ([example](http://pmburgess.blogspot.com/2006/02/irregular-plurals.html?m=1)).

Comment: A term already mentioned by others (including FF years ago) and discounted.

Answer (score -2):

> The singular of people is person.

People and person are different words.

The plural of people is **peoples**; the plural of person is **persons**.

However a group of persons has a collective noun "people" that is in the singular but with plural agreement.

Thus we have:

1994   Dog World Aug. 112/3   *Respect for a companion, whether the companion is a dog, a cat, a horse or **a person** is very important.*

1963   E. H. Schafer Golden Peaches of Samarkand ii. 52   *The great Hsüan Tsung himself, like **many other noble persons**, was a trained performer on the wether drum.*

1991   Bellcore News 15 May 3/2   *I think we should trust our people more; I think we have **too many people** in management.*

2000   Guardian 2 Dec. (Travel section) 11/1   *The Domesday entry..shows that **the people** of Laxton were cultivating about 720 acres of arable land.*

1792   R. Bage Man as he Is III. lxv. 118   *It has been usual to suppose the English **a people** who bore misfortune with passion or with gloom.*

1999   N.Y. Rev. Bks. 22 Apr. 54/3   *The Ruthenians are a part of the family of east Slavic **peoples**.*

Comment: The downvote is possibly because this has all been covered before. / I'm not sure that 'suppletion' (tall / taller but bad / **worse**) covers the use of unrelated lexemes to cover singular and plural referents. //// I see that OP has removed the request for a list.

Comment: I downvoted because you should have written "the plural of person is persons **or people**" (with "people" being the more common plural in modern usage). In contexts like "five people" or "how many people", we aren't dealing with "a collective noun 'people' that is in the singular but with plural agreement". "People" is just a plural noun in that kind of context, and it acts as the plural counterpart to "person": "one person, two people, three people..."

Comment: @herisson *you should have written "the plural of person is persons or people"* It may be idiosyncratic but I do not believe that. I wrote *People and person are different words.*, and that is true - they do not share a common root. It would be accurate to say *People* is often used to describe several persons but it is not the plural of person". You may see a difference between **1** "Persons found trespassing will be prosecuted" and **2** "People found trespassing will be prosecuted".

Comment: "go" and "went" don't share a common root either but it's standard to refer to "went" as the past tense of "go". The concept of suppletion (mentioned in Laurel's answer) is all about word-forms that do not share a common root coming to be used as different forms of the same word

Comment: I agree with you but do not see the parallel.